# How to safely move space around partitions between different operating systems

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I would like to move some space from a Windows partition (sda2) to a Ubuntu partition (sda5 or sda4?). However, I'm a novice in setting up partitions and the bootloader.

From other questions, I've seen that the partitions can't be mounted when messing with them. For this, people advised using a live USB with Ubuntu or with GParted. People have also mentioned using Windows for resizing its partitions (and disabling fast-startup) and GParted for Ubuntu, afterwards. However, beyond this I don't know much else. I know that stuff can break if the offset of the boot partitions changes and I don't update the bootloader, which I don't know how to do. Do I have to deal with this in this case? I ask this because sda2 and sda4/5 are consecutive. Are there any other caveats I should look out for?

A smaller question I have is why is sda5 alone inside sda4?

[image: Partitions]

Comment: * why is sda5 alone inside sda4* Well, sda4 is an extended partition, I think it's created this way when you installed Ubuntu alongside windows.

Comment: Regrettably, messing around with partitions is never safe. Before doing it, I would advice making proper backups.

Comment: A *safer* option would be creating a new partition instead of moving them, and maybe move your `/home` to that partition.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thank you for your insights. I'll probably backup and try it. If everything goes south I'll just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: "If everything goes south" happens more than we would like. A typo, a bad sector, a crash, etc. Partitioning is *risky*. You could lose both OS without warning. Prepare and protect to prevent a bad day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)